# Fetch Logged in Location Using Google API

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a small gadget for a company through which I can record the time in which my employees have signed in/out to Gmail(not mobile logins) from within their premises. Its pretty much to automate the clock in clock out application that they currently have. For this, I need to be able to grab either the ip address/latitude-longitude without using any other third party service. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to have the employees visit a Google Sites page with an AppsScript embedded in it after which you can record the time.

If you don't want to do this and rely only on login to gmail, you may be able to do it with  contextual gadgets for Gmail but that is out of the scope of Apps Scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting stuck with the same idea and i am probably going to have to use the google site option. But, How about grabbing the ip-address though? is that possible with google apps scripts?